# optional index signature in typescript

Tags: typescript

I want to be able to take a type like this:

```
export interface NodesState {
  attr1: number;
  attr2: number;
  attr3: number;
}
```

And give the user the ability to namespace the type.

So this is legal:

```
{
  namespace1: {
    attr1: 100,
    attr2: 150,
    attr3: 200
  },
  namespace2: {
    attr1: 300,
    attr2: 400
  }
}
```

But it is also legal with no namespaces:

```
{
  attr1: 200,
  attr2: 100,
  attr3: 200
}
```

I've tried this:

```
export type MakeState<T> = T & {
  [key: string]?: Partial<T>
}
```

But this is not valid typescript.

Is what I am trying to do possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, that's what you're looking for:

```
type MakeState<T> = T & { [index: string]: T }
```

Usage:

```
declare const state: MakeState<NodesState>;

state.attr1;       // `number`
state["foo"]       // `NodesState`
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgOQgBNgBnAZRk1TgG8AoOOamKARgC44kBXAWwBGaANyNmMVgCYuvQSLEsoAZhn8hUUQF969GAE8weALKYA1sErVgAHgAqAPjgBeOLbgAyOnADayEiC5SVmQAcwBdLjdtehJsABtMKDxsCCQguCCrLhNzS1RrQhIKKlR7UXpM1AA6RTZhOAB6BrgAA1l1FoqS4G8AInQICF6wxuaWwrI84BagA)